# How to allow for multiple v-list-group to be open at once (override default vue behavior)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 2 v-list-groups and am trying to allow the user to have them both open at the same time. Vue's default behavior is to only allow one to open at a time, and I can't seem to override that behavior.

I am using vuetify 2.6 and have tried to use the multiple prop, but it doesnt work. I have also tried to individually assign the :value prop to render "true" for both v-list-groups, but nothing seems to work.

```
      <v-list-group>
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Networking</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(setting, i) in itemsettingsNetworking"
          :key="i"
          :class="{'active': openMenu == setting[0]}"
          @click="menu_change(setting[0])"
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ setting[0] }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>

      <v-list-group>
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Interfaces</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(setting, i) in itemsettingsInterface"
            :key="i"
            :class="{'active': openMenu == setting[0]}"
            @click="menu_change(setting[0])"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ setting[0] }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:expand`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list/#props-expand) prop on the v-list to disable automatic collapse of groups:

```html
<v-list expand>
  <v-list-group>...</v-list-group>
  <v-list-group>...</v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-list expand>
              <v-list-group>
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Networking</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(setting, i) in itemsettingsNetworking"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ setting }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>

      <v-list-group>
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Interfaces</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(setting, i) in itemsettingsInterface"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ setting }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
      </v-list>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  `,
  data(){
    const buildList = (prefix, length) => Array.from({length}, (_,i) => prefix+i)
    return {
      itemsettingsInterface: buildList('interface ', 1),
      itemsettingsNetworking: buildList('network ', 1),
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```